# props.history not found when using withRouter

Tags: reactjs, react-router, higher-order-components

I'm attempting to setup a simple drop-down that will enable different routes when the user chooses a different item from the select menu.

I've wrapped my component with the HOC withRouter() that I thought would pass in all props from the router.

When I click on each select option I'm told that props is undefined, what am I missing here?

```
import React, { Component } from "react";
import { withRouter } from "react-router-dom";

class Dropdown extends Component {
  handleChange(e) {
    this.props.history.push(`/${e.target.value}`);
  }

  render() {
    return (
      <>
        <select name="" className="Dropdown" onChange={this.handleChange}>
          <option value="top">Top</option>
          <option value="new">New</option>

          <option value="best">Best</option>
        </select>
      </>
    );
  }
}

export default withRouter(Dropdown);
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I think you forget to bind your `handleChange` function  so you can bind fuction after state like this

```
 constructor(props) {
    super(props)
    this.handleChange = this.handleChange.bind(this);
  }
```

or you can do like this

```
 <select name="" className="Dropdown" onChange={this.handleChange.bind(this)}>
```

or you can just simply do like this.

```
handleChange =  async e => {
    this.props.history.push(`/${e.target.value}`);
}
```

Answer (score 0):

I think you need to bind your `handleChange` method to `this` explicitly. Try adding a constructor to the `Dropdown` class like:

```
  constructor(props) {
    super(props)
    this.handleChange = this.handleChange.bind(this);
  }
```

That's at least how they do it in the documentation here: https://reactjs.org/docs/handling-events.html